# How to filter in mysql with "LIKE" on column type "text" using php "sprintf"

Tags: php, mysql

I need help  to filter column with type "LONGTEXT" using `LIKE` within php statement. Text I want to filter contain "HIL"

Already tried using `mysql_real_escape_string('HIL')`  but still error, below is the code i am using now:

```
$umr_query=sprintf("SELECT * FROM customers_umr WHERE umrCat LIKE '% HIL %'");
```

expected php able to show sorted mySQL table, as tested in SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM customers_umr WHERE umrCat LIKE '% HIL %'
```

that this query works

Thank you

Comment: How do you execute this query in PHP?

Comment: All you have done is put characters into a string variable. You have not passed that string to the database to be executed.

Comment: You should also be getting a warning `Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in` HINT: you dont need to us `sprintf()` in this situation

Comment: You probably need to read [the PDO section of the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) And/Or a few PHP/MySQL tutorials

Comment: _expected php able to show sorted mySQL table_ Another Hint: If you want the result (once you get one) to be sorted then you also need to lookup `ORDER BY` in the MySQL manual

Comment: Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Answer (score -1):

This query is searching for " HIL " not "HIL"

```
$umr_query=sprintf("SELECT * FROM customers_umr WHERE umrCat LIKE '% HIL %'");
```

remove the spaces

```
$umr_query=sprintf("SELECT * FROM customers_umr WHERE umrCat LIKE '%HIL%'");
```

Comment: There is no real reason to assume that `LIKE '% HIL %'` is wrong, specially as the OP says the ran that in that state somehow anyway! There are so many other errors in the script anyway

Comment: OP says: Text I want to filter contain "HIL" - His query searches for " HIL " - it's very clearly wrong and your downvote is unwarranted.

Comment: So what if the text the OP is looking for is `The HIL are alive with the sound of music`

Comment: It's clear to me .. you seem confused, perhaps you should ask.

Comment: Afterall its not even the most obvious error in that code. The `sprintf()` will generare a warning, there appears to be no attempt to actually pass that query (right or wrong) to the databsase i.e. `query()` or `execute()` etc etc

Comment: Once the query is passed to the db though it won't find what he is looking for.

Comment: Or will it. Like the OP said, they tested it presumably in phpMyAdmin or something similiar